# uWSGI: how to include multiple app configuration in one yaml?

Tags: uwsgi

I found this example configuration in XML in `uWSGI`'s doc http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example#a3Web2PyinstancesoneXMLconfiguration

Can the same configuration be translated into `YAML`?

Answer (score 1):

The same rule applies:

```
app1:
  socket: xxx
  ...

app2:
  socket: yyy
  ...

app3:
  socket: zzz
  ...
```

then

uwsgi --yaml yourfile.yml:app1

uwsgi --yaml yourfile.yml:app2

uwsgi --yaml yourfile.yml:app3